MySql Server cannot be started on M
Met with the problem that MySql Server cannot be started on a Mac machine. Tried to download the MySql Server Community edition(8.4.0) and MySQLWorkBench.
When I openned MySQLWorkBench and setup some connection. The connection show No connection established error message. Then, I double checked MySQL tab in the bottom in the System Settings. Active instance and installed instace are with red dots, which says they are not running. I clicked on Start MySQL Server. Then the red dots flashed in green for very short time before they turned to be red again.
Tried to install MySQL Server and WorkBench multiple times. But could not resolve the issue. Added mysql to the PATH.


this is not a programming issue, SO is not the right place to ask about it. Superuser sister site of SO can orovide you with support. 2) even there you will not get help because there is nothing in your question that would enable them to help. You need ti check out mysql and macos logs for clues.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To resolve this issue and allow MySQL to start you should do the following:
open your System Settings.
scroll down to and select MySql on the left.
select the Configuration tab.
uncheck Keyring Data File.
click Apply.
then Reboot.
This is a known issue with MySQL 8.4 for Mac.
